# Evaluate the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, infinite-product

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$$

I've seen some similar questions asked. But this one is different from all these. Euler product does not apply. One cannot simply factorize $\left(1-\frac{2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$ since the $\sqrt{2}$ on top will prevent terms from cancelling. Any help will be appreciated!

Note: we are expected to solve this in 2 mins.

Comment: there is a formula for partial products, but it's not so simple: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B1-2%2F(2n%2B1)%5E2,%7Bn,1,Infinity%7D%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{%
\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{1 - {2 \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}}}} =
\prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{1 - {1/2 \over \pars{n + 1/2}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}
{\bracks{\prod_{n = 1}^{N}\pars{n + 1/2 - \root{2}/2}}
\bracks{\prod_{n = 1}^{N}\pars{n + 1/2 + \root{2}/2}} \over
\bracks{\prod_{n = 1}^{N}\pars{n + 1/2}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}
{\pars{3/2 - \root{2}/2}^{\overline{N}}\pars{3/2 + \root{2}/2}^{\overline{N}} \over \bracks{\pars{3/2}^{\overline{N}}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\Gamma^{2}\pars{3/2} \over
\Gamma\pars{3/2 + \root{2}/2}\Gamma\pars{3/2 - \root{2}/2}}\,
\lim_{N \to \infty}
{\pars{N + 1/2 - \root{2}/2}!\pars{N + 1/2 + \root{2}/2}! \over
\bracks{\pars{N + 1/2}!}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pi/4 \over
\pars{-1/4}\Gamma\pars{1/2 + \root{2}/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2 - \root{2}/2}}\
\times
\\[2mm] &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}
{\bracks{\pars{N + 1/2 - \root{2}/2}^{N + 1 - \root{2}/2}}
\bracks{\pars{N + 1/2 + \root{2}/2}^{N + 1 + \root{2}/2}}
\expo{-2N - 1} \over
\pars{N + 1/2}^{2N + 2}\expo{-2N - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{{1 \over 2} + {\root{2} \over 2}}}
\times
\\[2mm] &\
\lim_{N \to \infty}
{\bracks{1 + \pars{1/2 - \root{2}/2}/N}^{N}
\bracks{1 + \pars{1/2 + \root{2}/2}/N}^{N}
 \over
\braces{\bracks{1 + \pars{1/2}/N}^{N}}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &
-\cos\pars{\pi\,{\root{2} \over 2}}\,
{\exp\pars{1/2 - \root{2}/2}\exp\pars{1/2  \root{2}/2} \over \bracks{\exp\pars{1/2}}^{2}} = \bbx{-\,\cos\pars{{\root{2} \over 2}\,\pi}}
\approx 0.6057
\end{align}

Answer (score 18):

**Hint**. One may recall [Euler's infinite product for the cosine function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html)

$$\cos x =\prod_{n=0}^\infty \left(1-\frac{4x^2}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2}\right),\qquad |x|<\frac \pi2.$$

Comment: @Daniel Li Here is a proof of the above infinite product: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204021/any-elementary-proof-for-eulers-product-formula-for-sine/1204275#1204275

Comment: I wish the 9 upvoters upvoted Jack D'Aurizio's linked answer.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : done! Jack d'Aurizio's answers are always the best of the lot.

Answer (score 2):

Maple says this is $$\sin(\pi (\sqrt{2}-1)/2)$$
and more generally
$$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{t^2}{(2n+1)^2} \right) = \frac{\sin(\pi (1+t)/2)}{1-t^2} $$

Comment: Ok Great. But where can I find result like this? Is this some well-known result?

Comment: See Olivier Oloa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the partial products

$$A_p=\prod_{n=1}^{p} \left(1-\frac{2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$$ a CAS produced 
$$A_p=-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right) \frac{\Gamma
   \left(p-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}$$ and using Stirling approximetion for large $p$, this leads to $$\log\left(\frac{\Gamma
   \left(p-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2} \right)=\frac{1}{2p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ then $$A_p =-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\right)$$